# Android Box M8 - Issues with QWERTY Wireless i8 keyboard

Tags: keyboard, external-keyboard

I just bought an M8 android TV Box [here](http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/111521935877?_trksid=p2059210.m2749.l2649&ssPageName=STRK%3AMEBIDX%3AIT) and as you can see, it has a remote QWERTY keyboard that i can't get to function properly...

I can use the touchpad (mouse) on it, but the keys in the keyboard just do nothing...

I've been messing with the input and language settings but nothing seems to work...

I dont think it might be a driver issue because the mouse pointer works...

What else can i do to diagnose the problem?

The box runs android 4.4.2

If any extra info is needed, just ask

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

What input method is chosen? If you have chosen Google voice typing then the keyboard won't work.

Try choosing Google keyboard. If that is not working, try downloading a third party keyboard app from play store and choosing it.

For a bluetooth keyboard to work, you have to pair the device with your tv box first

Comment: I have not chosen voice typing. Haven't found a third party app that works, do you have one you recommend? I have tried everything that i could remember of...

Comment: Did you try any third party app?

Comment: I tried many, can't remember the names though and I'm not close to the box, sorry :/ I can get back when I can have access to the box

Comment: @AnteroDuarte is that a mini keyboard with a USB dongle?

Comment: Yes, but a wired keyboard won't work also. Neither a bluetooth keyboard without an adapter (using the box's built in bluetooth)

Answer (score 0):

hi just had same problem
first keypad coming up in japanese
went into settings
language & input
there was a check box next to japanese which was ticked
then of course i looked around checked some boxes and hey presto when i went back into apps the keypad not functioning

So back to settings
under keyboard & input methods there is a line Default click on this and make sure Harware is OFF
because I like an idiot had turned it on and it is only for Physical keyboard
silly me
hopefully your keyboard will be back

Comment: also there is option for android english (us) or (uk) other options includ remote and English - chose English because the Android English (UK) option the keyboard is huge ..... unless this is preferable  ....thank you to admins for this easy post as guest feature .. fantastic - hope my answer helps some folk out there cos i was stumped for a while

Comment: The device in the question does have a physical keyboard. The question is about that, not a keyboard app.

Answer (score -1):

plug the USB for the remote directly into the M8 android TV Box.